# Different Donation Accounts for Crowdfunding on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to make a website where I add different Crowdfunding Campaigns. Im using WordPress. I want that for the different campaigns you can see on my website how much already got donated and how much is the goal. Every campaign are from different projects so I want that the donations directly go to the bank account or just stripe account e.t.c of the projects. The only solutions I found cost 300 dollars a year and because its a non profit project I can not afford this. Please help me to do something good and help some children with this website. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a link with 10 donation plugins for WordPress. Hope one of them may fit your needs. Good luck with your project ^^

https://kinsta.com/blog/wordpress-donation-plugins/